# VB.NET Bubble Sorting not sorting

Tags: vb.net, bubble-sort

the problem given here is an error I have obtained when trying to sort my set values via bubble sorting method. Below is the code and the error i would obtain would be 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' after the first pass. Below is the entire code

```
Public Class Form1
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ourArray(20) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    ourArray(0) = 20
    ourArray(1) = 12
    ourArray(2) = 1
    ourArray(3) = 15
    ourArray(4) = 5
    ourArray(5) = 9
    ourArray(6) = 10
    ourArray(7) = 4
    ourArray(8) = 3
    ourArray(9) = 8
    ourArray(10) = 2
    ourArray(11) = 6
    ourArray(12) = 13
    ourArray(13) = 14
    ourArray(14) = 7
    ourArray(15) = 17
    ourArray(16) = 11
    ourArray(17) = 16
    ourArray(18) = 18
    ourArray(19) = 19


    Do While ourArray(i) > ourArray(i + 1)
        Dim iTemp As Integer
        For iPass = 0 To 1
            For i = 0 To 19
                If ourArray(i) > ourArray(i + 1) Then
                    iTemp = ourArray(i)
                    ourArray(i) = ourArray(i + 1)
                    ourArray(i + 1) = iTemp
                End If
            Next
        Next iPass

        Dim assist As String
        For i = 0 To 19
            assist = assist & ourArray(i) & vbNewLine

        Next
        MsgBox(assist)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

The goal is to press the given button when the program starts, and have the program sort the given random values in the correct order with each pass/button press. Example: start program, press sort button, values 4,5,3,2,1 appear in a message box. press button again, one of the values will be in the correct spot. 5,4,3,2,1 -> 1,4,3,2,5 -> 1,2,4,3,5 -> 1,2,3,5,4 -> 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: As suggested, you need to learn how to debug. You don;t fix issues like this simply by reading the code. That's obviously the first option but, when nothing jumps out, you need to execute the code and watch it in action, not just look at the final result. You should know exactly what each line of code is supposed to so you can use the debugger to check whether it actually does that. As soon as reality diverges from expectation, you've found an issue. Even if you can't solve the problem, at least you can provide us with far more relevant information.

Comment: It should be quite simple to find where you're using an invalid index but here's a clue. Your loop says this: `For i = 0 To 19`. Inside the loop you have this: `ourArray(i + 1)`. Dos that really make sense?